# Does this soil get compacted by occasional heavy vehicle traffic?

Tags: pressure

Soil compaction can occur through heavy vehicle traffic. I attached a picture (see below). There are three samples approx. to 5m distance to each side of a paved road. Vehicle traffic is sprodically (few times in a year, e.g. at harvest).

Do you think at the sampling points in the soil (0-30-cm depth) compaction could have occurred through vehicle traffic? The blue area is untilled, i.e. more aggregate stability. The grey part is tilled, i.e. soil aggregate structure is loose.*

[image: road runs between two fields]

*The thing is, I noticed very high accumulation of soil organic matter under the blue area which also had lots of vegetation one yr prior to sampling -- unlike the grey area which has been cropland for long time. It is said that compaction can suppress mineralization of soil organic matter because of lower aeration in soil which inhibits decomposer communities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

30cm depth over 5m distance is approximately a cone with an angle of 3.5 degrees. This is outside the 45 degrees angle commonly assumed for influence of compaction or surcharge load. It means it could not benefit from traffic.

If anything this zone could have been negatively impacted.

According to Terzaghi this will by the bulging area of compression influence plane.

Comment: so does this mean likely yes or no? I'm a little bit confused by the wording." could have been negatively impacted." Thank you again!

Comment: means, definitely no.